# NRPE command skips sudo command when called from remote host

Tags: nagios

**Issue :** The tmp file clearing script is able to execute successfully on nagios client machine. 
When same script called from the nagios master, the script is executed but it skips sudo line in the script. 
Can some one help me on this.

### **nrpe.cfg :**

root@nagislave:/tmp# grep -i usedspace /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg | grep -v '#'

```
command[usedspace_bash]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/tmp_space.sh
```

### **Sudo permission:**

root@nagislave:/etc/sudoers.d# cat nagios-test

```
nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/rm
```

### **Script:**

root@nagislave:/etc/sudoers.d# cat /usr/local/nagios/libexec/tmp_space.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
used_space=`df -h /tmp | grep -v Filesystem | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//g'`

if [ $used_space -le 10 ]
then
   echo "tmp FS OK - $used_space% of disk space used."
elif [ $used_space -gt 11 ]
then
   sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
   d=`df -h /tmp | grep -v Filesystem | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//g'`
   echo "OK - House keeping done on /tmp FS and now $d% of disk space used"
else
   echo "UNKNOWN"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable terminal-less access in sudo by disabling `requiretty` for this command. a tty (*ie* interactive usage) is required by default because otherwise this can help escalate security holes. So if you're fine with this, replace:

```
nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/rm
```

with:

```
Cmnd_Alias        NAGIOSRM = /bin/rm
nagios            ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: NAGIOSRM
Defaults!NAGIOSRM !requiretty
```

The Cmnd_Alias isn't mandatory but recommended, and becomes mandatory if you need extra parameters. This will allow only the rm command run by nagios.

Check `man 5 sudoers` for more informations.